# iOS: how to change colour/font of some characters of a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring

in my app i have to change the font of a part of **`string`** which comes from `JSON` response

```
> "<span class=\"drop_data_user\">Andrew James</span> liked your comment
> \"hiiiiiiiiiiiiiii\" that you posted."
```

to convert it in attributed string i am using the following code

```
NSAttributedString *attr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[NotificationTxt dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                          NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:@(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                                     documentAttributes:nil
                                                                  error:nil];
```

I want to change the font colour of the sender

Comment: How do you define that "Andrew James" is the sender? Will it always be between that particular span html tag?

Comment: yes it always be in between span tag

Comment: Since that tag won't be "interpreted" but committed (tested on Playground), I'd suggest to find it with `rangeOfString:`, a `NSRegularExpression` (if it's always the same one), `NSScanner`, etc. and add (or replace it) yourself a HTML tag defining a color for it.

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090597/how-to-add-css-of-an-html-to-nsattributedstring

Comment: did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrS = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"My String"];
[attrS addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
[attrS addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(3, 6)];

self.myLabel.attributedText = attrS;
```

For fonts use

```
[attrS addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20] range:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];
```

Comment: how can i use this code if range is dynamic as in my ques string comes from json response

Comment: Calculate where in the string your Sender is and adjust the range accordingly. I don't have enough information to show you.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use it as follows.

```
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"Teslimat: ", selectedReservationModel.DateLabel];
        NSMutableAttributedString *attrS = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: dateString];
        [attrS addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[GenericUtility getOpenSansBoldFontSize:12] range:NSMakeRange(0, 8)];
        [attrS addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[GenericUtility getOpenSansRegularFontSize:12] range:NSMakeRange(9, selectedReservationModel.DateLabel.length)];
        lblDeliveryDate.attributedText = attrS;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to fulfil your task is to use CSS inlined in the text, then parsing HTML as you do will change the color too (I'm using Swift syntax, but I believe you can easily convert it to ObjC):

```
let text = "<span class=\"drop_data_user\">Andrew James</span> liked your comment \"hiiiiiiiiiiiiiii\" that you posted."
let colouredAuthorText = "\(text)<style>.drop_data_user { color: #FEB600; }</style>"
```

Then just parse `colouredAuthorText` (which is created by appending style to the original text) instead of the original, and you should be good to go.